# AutoLayout Constraints on UITableViewCell of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, size-classes

I am using a `UITableView` and using the `UITableViewCell` `Subtitle` Style that is provided by Apple.

I am also using the Preferred Fonts so that they work with the Dynamic Type. If the user goes to Settings and changes the UI font size, it also affects the font in my view.

I am also allowing it to dynamically choose the row height based on the length of the text using row.estimatedRowHeight. This is great because with larger fonts and having multiple line text, the cells will adjust accordingly.

Using images is what is the problem. Images are of different sizes so scale them down. The scaling is sort of a hit or miss for the automatic cell height. It may not be done in time so the system calculation of the height may compute wrong.

My question then is, can I manually add constraints to the `UITableViewCell`'s `imageView` property so that it has a set width and height of 88 pixels. This way, even if the picture isn't done resizing yet, it will at least calculate the height of the containing cell properly?

OR, maybe better to ask this: Is it possible to have a static width/height for the image when the cell and text labels resize dynamically based on content length and size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good library for creating UI dynamically. It's called Cartography
https://github.com/robb/Cartography

Here code that helps to create resizable cell by image view height:

```
import UIKit
import Cartography

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var resizableImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func configurate() {

    constrain(self.resizableImage) { view1 in
        view1.width == view1.height
        view1.top == view1.superview!.top
        view1.bottom == view1.superview!.bottom
    }

    constrain(self.resizableImage) { view1 in
        view1.height == 88
    }
}
```

}